# Finding a string in a particular column

Tags: excel, vba

For testing purpose, we need to enter a value at Waypoint ID. Then we need to press Save Record or Find Record.

DataEntryPage
[image]

Problem 1: Subroutine FindRecord is not working. Macro assign FindRecord1

Problem 2: Subroutine SaveRecord is not working. Macro assign SaveRecord

Attach Workbook with name "[Problem.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11-jvIOI0mCe1q7adxKtpmm_yKIOpbZTN/view?usp=sharing)"

I am finding a string in a particular column "WayPointID" in Observations worksheet. WaypointID is always unique.

```vb
Sub FindRecord(WyPt)
    
    Dim Value As String
        
    WyPtRow = 0
    ReadRow = 2
    Value = Cells(ReadRow, 2).Select  'Observation Sheet-WayPointID
        
    While Value <> ""
        If WyPt = Value Then
            WyPtRow = ReadRow
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ReadRow = ReadRow + 1
        Value = Cells(ReadRow, 2)
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

---

```vb
Sub FindRecord1(WyPt)

WyPt = Trim(DEFrm.Cells(6, 2))
Call FindRecord(WyPt)

If WyPtRow > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Data Already Exists in Observations Worksheet" ' Data Already Exists
Else
    MsgBox "Data Does not exist in Observations Worksheet"
End Sub
```

---

```vb
Sub SaveRecord()

WyPt = Trim(DEFrm.Cells(6, 2))
Call FindRecord(WyPt)

If WyPtRow > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Data Already Exists in Observations Worksheet"
    Call ReturnFoundRecord(WyPtRow)        ' Data Already Exists
Else
    Call AddNewRecord          'New Record
End If        'WyPtRow > 0 Then
End Sub
```

If the Waypoint ID exists in the Observations worksheet it should say Data already exists in save record subroutine and then call the other subroutine ReturnRecordFound - Which is basically pasting the data from Observation sheet to Data Entry Form. Otherwise, if no data exists then it should add new record.

Comment: When you say *it's not working* what do you mean? You get an error? Nothing is found? Results differ from expected?

Answer (score 0):

Your line `Value = Cells(ReadRow, 2).Select` in `FindRecord` should throw a runtime error 1004.

You can't assign the `Range.Select` method to a `String` variable.

If you change `Select` to `Value` this will assign the value of the cell to your variable `Value`.

You should consider changing your variable names to ones that don't already exist within the VBA language. e.g. `MyValue` instead of `Value`.

---

`WyPtRow` isn't passed between the Subs so unless it's declared somewhere as a global scope variable, `WyPtRow` will be `0`, `Nothing`, `Empty` or `""` (depending on it's data type) in each procedure you use it in (as you haven't assigned any values to it expect for just before the end of your procedures after performing some actions).

Either pass `WyPtRow` back to your other procedures or consider giving the variable some kind of global scope.

Comment: if possible can you show changes in the code??

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next solution. It uses a function instead of a Sub and arrays to make the code faster:

```
Function FindRecord(WyPt As String) As Long
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, lastR As Long, i As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet. Maybe Worksheets("Observation Sheet-WayPointID")
 lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arr = shrange("B2:B" & lastR).Value
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
     If arr(i, 1) = WyPt Then FindRecord = i + 1: Exit Function
 Next i
End Function

Sub FindRecord1(WyPt)
 Dim WyPt As String, DEFrm As Worksheet, WyPtRow As Long
 
 Set DEFrm = Worksheets("your necessary sheet(DEFrm)")
 WyPt = Trim(DEFrm.cells(6, 2).Value)
 WyPtRow = FindRecord(WyPt)

 If WyPtRow > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Data Already Exists in Observations Worksheet" ' Data Already Exists
 Else
    MsgBox "Data Does not exist in Observations Worksheet"
 End Sub

 Sub SaveRecord()
 Dim WyPt As String, DEFrm As Worksheet, WyPtRow As Long
 
 Set DEFrm = Worksheets("your necessary sheet(DEFrm)")
 WyPt = Trim(DEFrm.cells(6, 2).Value)

 WyPtRow = FindRecord(WyPt)
 If WyPtRow > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Data Already Exists in Observations Worksheet"
    Call ReturnFoundRecord(WyPtRow)        ' Data Already Exists
 Else
    Call AddNewRecord          'New Record
 End If
End Sub
```

Please, take care to correctly set `DEFrm` worksheet...